# Подключить домен через nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx, бот, домен, веб-сайт

Я совсем не разбираюсь, у меня есть бот написанный на node js, он генерирует ссылки, домен на котором он генерирует ссылки нужно подключить через nginx, каким образом это сделать.

У меня есть часть инструкции:
Переходи в корень, потом etc
Потом nginx
site aviable в ней создай файл с названием твоего домена
В файле домена нужно написать:
server {
listen 80
listen [::]:80

Дальше инструкция утеряна, что нужно написать? и как бот поймёт что это мой домен? в директории домена нужно что-то разместить?

Бот установлен на VPS ОС- UBUNTU20

Comment: Нужно еще ссылку в `/etc/nginx/site-enabled/` добавить, перезагрузить nginx, добавит A-запись на DNS-сервер с указанием ip-адреса вашего VPS

Comment: Помогите пожалуйста, я поставил домен на клауд, как нужно добавить запись?